# laravel вставить данные в базу по индексам

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, индексация, индексы

Всем Привет, Может кто сказать как вставить в бд данные по индексам ? 
Вот например код который просто вставляет данные в бд.

Таблица users

```
 $field = new TestModel();
 $field->id = $id;
 $field->name = $name;
 $field->phone = $phone;
 $field->save();
```

В базе данных например есть таблица userinfo, нужно сделать так, чтобы при вставке данных в users таблица userinfo вставила теже данные в столбцы привязанные по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

Если у таблицы есть индекс, то любые вставленые данные автоматом индексируються по этому полью.

[Создание индекса в сушествуюшей таблице](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

[Создание таблицы с индексом](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys)